# wget: using wildcards in the middle of the path

Tags: bash, url, download, wget

I am trying to recursively download .nc files from: `https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/*/*/*/netcdf/*.nc`

A target link looks like this one:

```
https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/1992/11/goes07/netcdf/
```

and I need to exclude this:

```
https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/1992/11/goes07/csv/
```

I do not understand how to use wildcards for defining path in `wget`.

Also, the following command (a test for year 1981 only), only downloads subfolders 10, 11 and 12, failing with {01..09} subfolders:

```
for i in {01..12};do wget -r -nH -np -x --force-directories -e robots=off https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/1981/${i}/goes02/netcdf/; done
```

Comment: Take a look at https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/robots.txt and stop what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry Cyrus, could you clarify your comment?

Comment: It categorically means that you are NOT allowed to perform data harvesting in the manner that you are attempting.  You likely won't get help from anyone who respects Provider/Site directives, which is what the W3 standards outline for "proper" and "ethical" use of the internet.  If you proceed, that means that you are going against "public notification" and could be pursued legally for bypassing that notice.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not understand how to use wildcards for defining path in `wget`.

According to [GNU Wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

> File name wildcard matching and recursive mirroring of directories are
> available when retrieving via FTP.

so you must not use one in URL provided when working with HTTP or HTTPS server.

You might combine `-r` with `--accept-regex urlregex` to

> Specify a regular expression to accept(...)the complete URL.

Observe that it should match whole URL, for example if I wish pages linked in [GNU Package blurbs](https://www.gnu.org/manual/blurbs.html) which contain `auto` in path I could do that by

```
wget -r --level=1 --accept-regex '.*auto.*' https://www.gnu.org/manual/blurbs.html
```

which result in download main pages of autoconf, autoconf-archive, autogen, automake. Note: `--level=1` is used to prevent going further down than links shown in blurbs.